# Meaning of {0!s} as formatting parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am quite familiar with python3 formatting options but I haven't faced a `{0!s}` option before.
In particular the format I encountered was something like:

```
'{0!s}.xml'.format('VID/' + file)
```

which as far as I get it it's just a way to render the output of `str(arg)` and in my case `str('VID/')` according to [this explanation](https://pyformat.info/).

So the output would be something like:
`VID/000.xml` for example.

Since my argument is already a `str` in this case I did not see any difference  when I just omit the whole formatting parameter (use `{}` instead of `{0!s}`).

Other experiments I made was omitting the leading 0 which produces the same result, while replacing it with another number like 1 produces an error:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Can someone explain what's the case with this formatting parameter? When should I use it etc?

Comment: Yes, it says to format the 0th parameter as string. Yes, that's redundant with what the default `{}` behaviour would do.

Comment: The error when you put `{1}` is because it will try to find the second element in the list given as parameter in the `format()` method. As `'VID/' + file` is a singleton, it cannot find a second element (resulting in the 'out of range' error).

Answer (score 1):

It's value conversion: https://pyformat.info/#conversion_flags

```
{0!s}.xml
```

Means "For the 0th argument, get the string to to put in the formatted string by calling the `__str__` method"

You can also use `{0!r}` to call the `__repr__` method instead